# Como agregar plugins a Ckeditor 5 de Django

Tags: django, ckeditor5

¿Tengo una duda con django-ckeditor-5, necesito agregar un plugin [showblocks](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/show-blocks.html#demo) que django-ckeditor lo trae por defecto, es posible hacerlo con django-ckeditor-5 ? O solo tienen disponibles los que dice [aquí](https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor-5/) ?

No encuentro nada relacionado con extraplugins con esta librería alguien sabe si se pueden añadir otros plugins ?